# li:marker and text not on same line on firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

How to make this item list text with li:marker appearing on same line.

By default on firefox, the navigator does not seem to align the text and the list style.

```html
<div id="block-views-articles-block-1" class="block block-views contextual-links-region clearfix">
      <h2 class="title">A la une</h2>
      <div class="content">
        <div
          class="view view-articles view-id-articles view-display-id-block_1 view-dom-id-0e5a7d89bbc6fd4dcdd56c23e9932434">
          <div class="view-content">
            <div class="item-list">
              <ul>
                <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
                  <a href="/fr/5e-edition-du-prix-departemental-recherche-provence-2021">
                    <div class="description"></div>
                    <div class="h2-like title">5e édition du Prix Départemental de la Recherche en Provence 2021</div>
                    <div class="picture"></div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even"><a
                  href="/fr/pouvoir-caresses-emission-arte-rochelle-ackerley-chercheuse-lequipe-corps-multisensorialite">
                  <div class="picture">
                  </div>
                  <div class="h2-like title">Le pouvoir des caresses : une émission sur ARTE avec Rochelle Ackerley,
                    chercheuse de l'Equipe Corps et Multisensorialité
                    <div/>
                    <div class="description"></div>
                </a>
                </li>
                <li class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd views-row-last"><a href="/fr/yearbook-2019-carnot-cognition">
                  <div class="picture"></div>
                  <div class="h2-like title">Yearbook 2019 Carnot Cognition</div>
                  <div class="description"></div>
                </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/matoeil/pen/abpmerO

Comment: Unclear what the problem is supposed to be here, both the snippet and your codepen appear to be showing the marker and the first line of list item text on the same line. (Pretty much as expected, with no additional CSS whatsoever being applied in the first place.)

Comment: @CBroe i have edited it . i just found out it is only on firefox

Comment: Make the `a` elements `display:block`, that appears to fix the Firefox issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to @CBroe, the a needs a display block but also the ul must be having an outside list style position to work

```
a {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```